# Converting React class component to functional component with hooks : Problem with event listeners

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I had a picture zooming component as a React class component. I then wanted to convert it to functional component and make it work with hooks. I almost have it down but I run into this problem that I can only scroll once in and once out. I'm using state variable size as a limit to zoom, starting at 30. But currently when I scroll it wont continuously keep zooming until limit but just a single step in and out. What is causing this limit and how can I fix it?

```
const ProductPicture = (props) => {

    const [size, setSize] = useState(30);
    
    const zoomTarget = useRef(null)

    const handleScroll = useCallback((event) => {
        if (event.deltaY > 0 && size < 50) {
            setSize(size + 2)
        } else if (event.deltaY < 0 && size > 20) {
            setSize(size - 2)
        } 
    })

    useEffect(() => {
        zoomTarget.current.addEventListener('wheel', handleScroll, true); 
        return() => {zoomTarget.current.removeEventListener('wheel', handleScroll, true)}
    },[]);

    return (
        <div className="livetods-product-image-container" style={{
            top: openAsModal() ? '25%' : '20%',
            left: openAsModal() ? '30%' : '',
            right: openAsModal() ? '30%' : '',
            width: size + "%"        
        }} >
    
        <div className="livetods-product-image-button-container" >
                    <div></div>             
                    <h6 className="livetods-product-image-name">{props.name}</h6>
                    <span className="livetods-modal-header-close-button" onClick={e => props.hideImage()}>&times;</span>
        </div>
        
            <div style={{width: "100%", height:"100%"}}>               
                <div ref={zoomTarget} style={{position: "relative"}}>
                    <div style={{position:'absolute', padding: '5px'}}>
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearchPlus} color={'red'} style={{ width: '20px', height: '20px', pointerEvents:"none"}}/>
                    </div>
                    <img src={props.src} style={{borderRadius: "5px", width: '100%'}} /> 
                </div>   
            </div>
    
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your handleScroll  (setSize & size) , are scoped to the original. IOW: when size changes you get a new instance of setSize / size while handleScroll is still using the old..

Comment: Could you elborate a bit more? I am very new to hooks I'm not understanding what is wrong. I put this version together from several tutorials

Comment: You need to add size to useCallback depedency array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an updater function to `setSize` instead of giving it a value. ([Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates))

```js
const handleScroll = useCallback((event) => {
    const deltaY = event.deltaY
    setSize((size) => {
        if (deltaY > 0 && size < 50) {
            return size + 2
        } else if (deltaY < 0 && size > 20) {
            return size - 2
        }
        return size
    })
}, [])
```

---

## Explanation

The `useCallback` hook cache the callback so that it will always get the same callback reference as long as no item in the dependency array has changed. (The code in the question misses the dependency array, which is not a valid usage) ([Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback))

The code in the question always reuse the same callback reference since no dependency array is given. In this case, inside the callback, `size` is always equals to its initial value (i.e. `30`) and set the size to either `30 + 2` or `30 - 2`.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now. HOWEVER, one more thing, now it zooms infinitely! It is not checking size < 50 or size > 20, it will go far beyond either way. I assume I am here also evaluating with old initial state, but from examples I look at it seems that I can simply access state by its variable???

Comment: @Jeekim I have updated my answers. I moved the whole value checking logic into the updater function.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your version of handlescroll, it will scroll correctly BUT it will get stuck once either limit is reached. If i zoom out to limit picture will get stuck there, same with zooming in.
I got it to work when I added [size] as a dependcy to useEffect ?!?! I honestly dont have much understanding about hooks yet, but this allows me to zoom to correct limits and then back again.

Comment: @Jeekim I forgot to return `size` in the updater function if none of the conditions is true. This causes it to return `undefined`. Doing arithmetic with `undefined` always results in `NaN`. This may explain the behaviour of getting stuck.